# Объясните конструкцию with as

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть небольшой пример вызова этой конструкции для открытия файлов:

```
# method1
with open('group.pickle', 'wb') as p:
    p.write(ser_pickle)

#method2
with open('group.pickle', 'wb') as p:
    pickle.dump(my_favourite_group, p)


#method1
with open('group.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as j:
    j.write(ser_json)

#method2
with open('group.json', 'w') as j:
    json.dump(my_favourite_group, j)
```

Что в данном случае значат части когда "as j: as p:", что за j и p?

Comment: Это как p = open... Но в конце блока будет автоматически вызван p.close()

Comment: А внизу часть вопроса? Я правильно понимаю, что j и p в данном случае переменные и хранят в себе файл, который я открыл?

Comment: Да без разницы p, j или вообще abvgd назвать - это просто название переменной, да.

Comment: это то же самое как давать свое название импортируемому модулю `import numpy as np`. Вы присваиваете файл какой-то переменной, с которой потом будете работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтение и запись файлов.

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
```

`open()` возвращает `объект файла`
и чаще всего используется с двумя аргументами: `open(имя файла, режим)`.

Хорошей практикой является использование ключевого слова `with` при работе с файловыми объектами.
Преимущество заключается в том, что файл правильно закрывается после завершения его набора,
даже если в какой-то момент возникает исключение.
Использование `with` также намного короче, чем написание эквивалентных блоков `try-finally`:

```
with open('workfile') as f:     # файловый объект с именем `f`
```

Если вы не используете ключевое слово `with`, вам следует вызвать `f.close()`,
чтобы закрыть файл и немедленно освободить все используемые им системные ресурсы.
Если вы явно не закроете файл, сборщик мусора в Python в конечном итоге уничтожит
объект и закроет открытый файл для вас, но файл может оставаться открытым некоторое время.
Другой риск состоит в том, что разные реализации Python будут выполнять эту очистку в разное время.

---

**Update**

> А можете подробнее объяснить то, что мы обсудили в комментариях? Чем в вашем коде является f? Она же не хранит сам файл?

Сам файл у вас находится где-то на диске, файловый объект с именем `f` содержит все необходимое для работы с этим файлом.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:     # файловый объект с именем `f`
   print(f)
   print(type(f))
   print(help(f))
   print(dir(f))
   print(f.__doc__)
   # ...
```